# Presto: Cast timestamp w/TZ to plain timestamp WITHOUT converting to UTC

Tags: sql, presto

This query in Presto:

```
select *, 
  cast(ts_w_tz as timestamp) as ts, 
  cast(substr(cast(ts_w_tz as varchar), 1, 23) as timestamp) as local_ts_workaround 
from (select timestamp '2018-02-06 23:00:00.000 Australia/Melbourne' as ts_w_tz);
```

Returns:

```
                   ts_w_tz                   |           ts            |   local_ts_workaround   
---------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------
 2018-02-06 23:00:00.000 Australia/Melbourne | 2018-02-06 12:00:00.000 | 2018-02-06 23:00:00.000
```

As you can see, the act of casting the timestamp with timezone to a timestamp has resulted in the timestamp being converted back to UTC time (eg `ts`). IMO the correct behaviour should be to return the 'wall reading' of the timestamp, as per `local_ts_workaround`.

I realise there are many posts about how Presto's handling of this is wrong and doesn't conform to the SQL standard, and that there is a fix in the works. But in the meantime this is a major pain since the effect is that there appears to be no built in way to get a localised timestamp withOUT timezone (as per `local_ts_workaround`).

Obviously, I have the string conversion workaround for now, but this seems horrible. I am wondering if anyone has a better workaround or can point out something that I have missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Issue tracking this bug: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7122 (timestamp W/TZ is converted back to whatever is session zone, not necessarily UTC). Your workaround is efficient, but combination of `format_datetime` + `parse_datetime` would be probably more "obviously correct".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like there's no great solution, but building off of the previous answer, I like this a little better... see the `date_format_workaround` column:

```
select *,
  cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(date_format(ts_w_tz, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')) as timestamp) as date_format_workaround,
  cast(ts_w_tz as timestamp) as ts,
  cast(substr(cast(ts_w_tz as varchar), 1, 23) as timestamp) as local_ts_workaround
from (select timestamp '2018-02-06 23:00:00.000 Australia/Melbourne' as ts_w_tz);
```

Comment: While it is still essentially passing through a string conversion and not ideal I agree it is more robust than my own workaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(from_iso8601_timestamp('2018-02-06T23:00:00.000Z') as timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question is specifically about the case where you already have a time stamp with time zone type.