# Athena - Stripping the 'Time Zone' part from the timestamp after converting from UTC to EST

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I'm converting the timestamp column, which is by default in UTC, into EST by using 'AT TIME ZONE' clause (America/New_York or EST5EDT). However, the resulting text displays the timestamp along with the time zone. E.g: '2022-10-12 07:30:00.000 EST5EDT' .

I tried casting it to timestamp, `cast(result as timestamp)`, but this converts it back to UTC.

Comment: Looks helpful: [sql - Presto: Cast timestamp w/TZ to plain timestamp WITHOUT converting to UTC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633900/presto-cast-timestamp-w-tz-to-plain-timestamp-without-converting-to-utc)

Comment: I can confirm: You have to play around with substrings. We had this usecase in our project already.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, your suggestion definitely helps. Thank you!